# kernel issues, trying to solve touchpad issue

Tags: kernel, nvidia, touchpad

recently purchased an Asus Rog GL503. I directly installed ubuntu on it and i first noticed that the touchpad wasn't working properly. I tried with mtrack but didn't work fine. I saw a chance upgrading the kernel from 4.15.0-33-generic to 4.18.5.
reading the guide from:

https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?103220-Is-your-ELAN1200-touchpad-not-working-on-Linux-D

but i get stuck on:

```
make install -j 8
with the following output:
rachele@Pc:~/linux-4.18.5$ sudo make install -j 8
[sudo] password for rachele: 
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.18.5 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.18.5 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.5
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.18.5 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.5
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.18.5 is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.18.5 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.10/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.18.5 /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.5
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.5
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/image.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/sec2/desc.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/nvdec/scrubber.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_method_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_nonctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/sw_ctx.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/gpccs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_sig.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_data.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_inst.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/gr/fecs_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_unload.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/ucode_load.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/unload_bl.bin for module nouveau
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/bl.bin for module nouveau

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.18.5 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:155: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:314: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

While i was doing the previous commands i noticed that i cannot resume the session if it goes in stand-by.

Comment: Judging by the line `kernel package linux-headers-4.18.5 is not supported`, I would say that the package you are trying to install on it is not the correct one for your device.

Comment: i managed to install via Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility .
The touchpad works a little bit smooth than before but it freeze sometimes..
does anybody got suggestions?